How to add shadow casting to a shader
I wrote my shader in unity to create a block like this in minecraft:
Shader "Custom/MinecraftBlock"
{
    Properties
    {
        _FrontTex ("Front", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BackTex ("Back", 2D) = "white" {}
        _LeftTex ("Left", 2D) = "white" {}
        _RightTex ("Right", 2D) = "white" {}
        _TopTex ("Top", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BottomTex ("Bottom", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _FrontTex;
            sampler2D _BackTex;
            sampler2D _LeftTex;
            sampler2D _RightTex;
            sampler2D _TopTex;
            sampler2D _BottomTex;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.normal = v.normal;
                return o;
            }
            
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col;

                if (i.normal.y > 0.5) col = tex2D(_TopTex, i.uv);
                else if (i.normal.y < -0.5) col = tex2D(_BottomTex, i.uv);
                else if (i.normal.x > 0.5) col = tex2D(_RightTex, i.uv);
                else if (i.normal.x < -0.5) col = tex2D(_LeftTex, i.uv);
                else if (i.normal.z > 0.5) col = tex2D(_FrontTex, i.uv);
                else col = tex2D(_BackTex, -i.uv);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}


It works, but it doesn't cast shadows. I have tried many methods from the internet but none of them helped. Is there a solution for my case?
I tried rewriting and using surface shaders, but there the final image was just blurry, and not suitable for my case.
P.S: don't judge me harshly, I don't understand much about shaders.
